# Error in React lib ---> TypeError: type is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get this error on line 9729 in the 'react-with-addons' library:

```
function autoGenerateWrapperClass(type) {
  return ReactClass.createClass({
    tagName: type.toUpperCase(),
    render: function() {
      return new ReactElement(
        type,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        this.props
      );
    }
  });
```

the line with `type.toUpperCase()` is throwing the error

anyone have an idea what could cause this?

(I get the same error in the plain old `react` library (not react-with-addons) and that is on line 9259.)

Comment: You're trying to render something that is not a component.

Comment: I don't think that's it

Comment: it looks like you're right, I wish the error message were less vague